# Sharing on Twitter using Custom View using SHK or Twitter Framework

Tags: ios5, twitter, sharekit

I am trying to share using ShareKit Or iOS5 Twitter framework. However, I need to have a custom twitter view. The view will take the user input - the message to be shared and post it directly if the user is logged in or prompt for authorization.

I am not sure how to customize the sharing view. Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As for shareKit: for iOS 4 devices it is quite easy - you just subclass SHKFormControllerLargeTextView and use your graphics.

If you want to use twitter.framework only, it is probably better not to use ShareKit - just use the framework directly. Great info is in WWDC 2011 video, and in Apple's sample app.